# Can't update WCF Service Reference - Service Works

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf, service, reference

I can't update my WCF-Service Reference after adding a new method. If i undo my changes it won't work, too. If i call the URI: `http://192.168.1.175:8001/WS` i can see the XML-File from the Service with all the methods. My client Application can also communicate with the server. If i enter the URI in the "WcfTestClient.exe" i'll get the same error as when i'll update my Service Reference:

```
HTTP-Status 503: Service Unavailable.
```

help appreciated.... :)

Comment: Yes, the service is running. I see the XML-Output in my browser, too.

Comment: Look at the config file for the host.  Specifically mex.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today. After poking around on the web I came to the conclusion there was something being cached somewhere. I search my computer for all instances of the service's DLL (Found 19, BTW) and deleted all of them. After rebuilding, everything started working as it should.